# Selenium WebDriver enters wrong digit information to input

Tags: c#, selenium, input, selenium-webdriver

For tests of my web site I use c# and Selenium web driver. And I have problems with fill input values. 
Code is like this:

```
// create some random digit value
int Value = (new Random()).Next(1, 999);
// enter this value to input
driver.FindElement(By.Id("SomeID")).Clear(); 
driver.FindElement(By.Id("SomeID")).SendKeys(Value.ToString());
```

It works but unfortunately not always. Sometimes if I want for example enter '100' to input it enters `1à0` or `10à`.

I have French keyboard and to enter digits you need to do it with shift pressed. If we press '0' with shift we will have '0', without shift 'à', etc
problem is not only with 0 but with 9, what is sometimes changed to 'ç' and all digits.

Does somebody knows this problem?

**EDIT 07/02**
This problem appears at IE9 only

Comment: Can you share the URL of this web-page?

Comment: so, are you entering 100 manually or code enter incorrect value when random returns 100?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question.........From the above code you can not give number dynamically.so, where were you entering the number

Comment: No, I cannot show url because it is internal beta version

Comment: 100 is an example, when random is 158 the entered result can be 15ç or 1(8

Comment: On a separate point, generally it is best not to use random numbers in a test. This may lead to unreproducible results.

Comment: Are you running just one thread of tests? I had a similar issue when running multiple threads, two sendKeys running in the same time can cause some mistyping if the characters needs the shift keys to be pressed.

Comment: I run several threads with different selenium servers